# Select component, which has point in id with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to select this table:

```
<table class="pane sortable" id="game.scores">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
    .....
</table>
```

I tried to do this:

```
Elements el = doc.select("table#game.scores");
System.out.println(el.html());
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this selector,

```
table[id=game.scores]
```

You can verify various selectors without running java code, [here](http://try.jsoup.org/)